# smarty foreach how does it work correctly?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have a problem with my smarty foreach. It does not output the right thing :S
I tried many things but it never worked.

```
$data = array(
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test")
    );

    $smarty->assign('invTalents', $data);

    return array(
        array(
        'type' => 'html',
        'html' => $smarty->fetch('*****/*****/smarty.tpl'),

        ),
    );
```

in smarty.tpl I got this:

```
    <table class="designedTable" style="width:96%; font-size:11px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="clear_first brdRight">
        </td><td class="white_last">
    </td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


    {foreach from=$invTalents item=data}
        <tr>
            <td class="clear_first brdRight">{$invTalents->data}</td><td class="white_last"><strong>0</strong></td>
        </tr>
        {/foreach}

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr><td class="clear_first brdRight"></td><td class="white_last"></td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: It may be useful to add details of the output seen vs expected

Comment: access like this {$data.name} or {$data.value}

Comment: My table didn't output anything. I tried it as you said @Lylo and it works perfectly :) thank you very much.

Comment: @exols: sorry for my little informations :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{foreach from=$invTalents item=data}
```

With this you loop through the `invTalents` variable and assign the current value to `data`. So in your output you need to use the data variable. Also you then need to access the array with the key(s) you defined in PHP, which are `name` and `value`.

```
{foreach from=$invTalents item=data}
    <tr>
        <td class="clear_first brdRight">{$data.name}</td><td class="white_last"><strong>{$data.value}</strong></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

More info and examples in the Smarty documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: Great :) thank you, this worked for me as I wanted. Now my table works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

@H34D, Please check below code.

```
$data = array(
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test"),
        array('name' =>  "name", 'value' => "test")
    );

$smarty->assign('invTalents', $data);
```

In your view you can access your array (i.e invTalents) by this way. (General Smarty Behavior)

```
{foreach $invTalents as $inv} 
 {$inv.name} 
 {$inv.value} 
{/foreach}
```

So As Per Exact behavior of your view code you can access array like below. (As Per Your Code Structure)

```
{foreach $invTalents as $inv}
    <tr>
        <td class="clear_first brdRight">{$inv.name}</td><td class="white_last"><strong>0</strong></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) sady it didn'T work for me because smarty strangely didn'T allow me to use "as $inv" It worked like Cornelius said: {$data.name} and {$data.value}

Comment: @H34D, It worked fine at my end & it's render the array in view file too... Have you tried as I've described above ?

Comment: I got this error message:
syntax error: expecting '=' after attribute name 'as'

Comment: I haven't got any error & working fine, If above error accrued then you need to use {foreach from=$invTalents item=data} instead of {foreach $invTalents as $inv} because your error says that expecting =  in error message.

Comment: Yes, it worked with {foreach from=$invTalents item=data} perfectly.
with this I used {$data.name]} and {$data.value} Now it works as i wished

Comment: Sorry I can't. I haven't got enough reputation -.-